# How to not display data in first component of UIPickerView until the start of specific row in second component?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipickerview

I apologize if this is a duplicate of the following questions, if so please mark as so:

[how to set the data in second component based on first component selection in UIPickerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453710/how-to-set-the-data-in-second-component-based-on-first-component-selection-in-ui)
[Not able to reload second compoenent based on value in first component in UIPickerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619754/not-able-to-reload-second-compoenent-based-on-value-in-first-component-in-uipick)

First, an illustration of what I currently have in my `UIPickerView`:
[image]

I currently have 2 components in my `UIPickerView`. I would the first component to not show until row 3 of the second component is selected, i.e. `Day(s)`.

I currently have the following simple code set up:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    if component == 0
    {
        return times_ARRAY[row]
    }
    else
    {
        return cycle_ARRAY[row]
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    if component == 0
    {

        return times_ARRAY.count
    }
    else
    {
        return cycle_ARRAY.count
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I'm not sure how to apply the simple logic.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable `daySelcted:Bool` and change these 2 delegate methods.

```
var daySelcted:Bool = false

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0
    {
        if !daySelcted
        {
        return 0
        }
        return times_ARRAY.count
    }
    else
    {
        return cycle_ARRAY.count
    }
}

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == 1 
    {
        if row == 2
        {
        daySelcted = true
        }
        else
        {
            daySelcted = false
        }
        pickerView.reloadComponent(0)

    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to work partially, but when I start scrolling the component one, all the rows in component one disappears

Comment: ok I just had to fixed `row == 2` to `row >=2` because component one was disappearing when I selected row > 2 in component two, does that seem right?

Comment: "I would the first component to not show until row 3 of the second component is selected, i.e. Day(s)." I thought you want to show component 0 when `row == 2`. Just change it to `row >= 2`